# Синтаксис языка программирования - Perl

Tags: perl

---

### -Из: https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata-

Если вы оцениваете массив в скалярном контексте, он возвращает длину массива. (Обратите внимание, что это не относится к спискам, которые возвращают последнее значение, как оператор запятой C, а также к встроенным функциям, которые возвращают все, что они хотят вернуть.) Следующее всегда верно:

```
scalar(@whatever) == $#whatever + 1; //#1
```

Некоторые программисты предпочитают использовать явное преобразование, чтобы не оставлять сомнений:

```
$element_count = scalar(@whatever); //#2
```

Не понятно что имеется ввиду в инструкциях выше, объясните пожалуйста что имеется в #1 и в #2...

Answer (score 1):

Конструкция `$#имя`, где имя - это имя массива `@имя` возвращает индекс последнего элемента. Так как в Perl'е первый индекс нулевой, то индекс последнего элемента на единицу меньше его длины. Поэтому длина массива на единицу больше. Тут как бы все абсолютно очевидно.

Конструкцией `scalar(@whatever) == $#whatever + 1;` хотели сказать, что `scalar(@whatever)` и `$#whatever + 1` равны.

`scalar` - это такая функция, которая, которая "форсирует" скалярный контекст. А массив в скалярном контексте возвращает как раз его длину.

Конструкцией `$element_count = scalar(@whatever);` просто сохранили значение длины массива в переменную. Не более.

Если Вы программировали до этого на "обычных языках программирования", то привыкли, что операнды определяют, как поведет себя операция или функция. То есть, если у нас операция `+`, то как оно для чисел будет сложение, для строк конкатенация. В перле же все наоборот - операция определяет, что делать. И если написано `$x + $y`, а `$x` и `$y` - строки, то это их проблема - они будут преобразованы в числа и сложены как числа. Для конкатенации строк есть есть точка. И если операнды вдруг не строки - это их проблема.

Уметь определять контекст - одно с важных умений Perl программиста. Иногда это бывает не так тривиально. особенно в этом плане отличается функция `reverse`, если ей передать строковую переменную. Она может по разному работать. Помедитируйте на досуге о том, что выведет данный код

```
my $x = "test";

print(reverse($x));

my $rt = reverse($x);
print ($rt);
```